# Improve caching performance in Mule

Tags: performance, caching, mule, anypoint-studio

I am using Anypoint 6.1 and Mule 3.8.1 and I'm finding problems with the performance and it looks like it is down to the cache scope.

The cache is a managed store (so I can invalidate the cache when new data is loaded) and has the following values:

- Max Entries: 1000
- Entry TTL: 84600
- Expiration Interval: 84600

The response returns approx 200 JSON records.

Is there anyway to improve this and make this a faster response?

Thanks

Comment: You need to make sure you are hitting the cache.. could you able to share your flow so that it can be checked?

Answer (score 0):

Expiration Interval is the frequency with which the object store checks for expired cached response events. It can be set as low as 1 seconds to hours, depending upon the message rate you are expecting, you can try different values to test performance of your application.

Also, try in-memory-object-store for your caching strategy, as it saves responses in system memory, so a little bit faster but have to be careful in usage to avoid OutOfMemory errors.